# How to Prevent double click on Save button

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, button, double-click

How do I prevent a user from clicking a save button twice and probably display something like "Please Wait" or Saving... in a VB.NET windows forms application. I am trying

```
Buttonsave.Focus = False
labelSaving.Visible = True
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many possibilities ...

This is a easy one

```
Try
   yourButton.enabled= false
   ' save
Catch(Ex as exception )
   'do something
Finally
  yourButton.enabled= true
End Try
```

Now, you can imporve this by performing "Save" into a task, checking the state, showing a "saving message"....

Comment: Hi to my @Downvoters, maybe you can say something else than perform a downvote on all answers?

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is probably

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    btnSave.Enabled = False
    btnSave.Refresh = True
    Try
        'save data
    Finally
        'always make sure it is enabled - even if there is an exception
        btnSave.Enabled = True
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to like this type of functionality in window application then we need to use **Background Worker**.

1) Start Background process when click on button.

2) stop Background process when process finished.

Also need to add Cursors.

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor (When process start)
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default   (When process finished)
```

Answer (score -1):

After clicking..disable it. or take the focus from the button

button.enabled = false

Comment: Taking the focus won't help I don't think